# Styling a 2nd image in the same image tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an image in one div styled with a class, and an alt tag so I can grab it in jQuery to generate a 2nd image when first image is clicked. I am having difficulty styling that second image to fit correctly in the div that I need it to go to.

I have gotten the movement to happen, but not sure how to style the second image without adding css to the jQuery.

```js
var images = ["joe.png", "brady.png","elway.png","manning.png"];
        
$('img[alt="montana"]').on("click",function(){
  $(".qb-choice").append("<img src='assets/images/joe.png' />");
});
```

```css
.card-img-top{
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card" style="width: 14rem;">
  <p class="card-text">MONTANA</p>
  <img class="card-img-top joe" src="assets/images/giphy.gif" alt="montana">
  <p class="card-text">180</p>
</div>
```

I need to resize the image that is in appended in jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
var images = ["joe.png", "brady.png","elway.png","manning.png"];
        
$('img[alt="montana"]').on("click",function(){
  $(".qb-choice").append("<img src='assets/images/joe.png' class='card-img-top joe'/>");
});
```

```css
.card-img-top{
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card" style="width: 14rem;">
  <p class="card-text">MONTANA</p>
  <img class="card-img-top joe" src="assets/images/giphy.gif" alt="montana">
  <p class="card-text">180</p>
</div>

<div class="qb-choice"></div>
```

Add classname to class attribute to the image tag

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you, it does.